# Understanding MVVM: simple non-working code

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to understand this pattern and all the logic that's behind it.

I don't think it's that hard, but still I'm failing in some easy tasks.

Let's make it clear with a non-working example that I wrote:

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Categories Category { get; set; }
    public Grid PresenterContent { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Model _model;
    public Model Model 
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_model != value)
            {
                _model = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Model);
            }
        }
    }

    public Grid PresenterContent
    {
        get
        {
            return Model.PresenterContent;
        }
        private set { }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Model = new Model();            
    }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding PresenterContent}"/>        
</Grid>
```

Now, I expect this to work when I run it, as I'm setting the `DataContext` to `ViewModel` which has a `PresenterContent` property.

(This property is both in the `Model` and the `ViewModel` because I don't know to work with child's property, in this case `Model.PresenterContent`.)

What actually happens is that an exception is thrown:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'PresenterContent' property not found on 'ViewModel' 'System.String' (HashCode=-903444198). BindingExpression: Path='PresenterContent' DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=-903444198); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'System.Object')..

and this says that there's no `PresenterContent` in the `ViewModel`, which is clearly wrong.
The exception is the same if I try to bind to `Model` property.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dude, you're getting it all wrong. You're not supposed to put a property of type `Grid` in your Model. The idea is to `separate` UI and data, not to tie them together even more.

Comment: Forget the types, this is just an example. As I wrote, the error comes even with the `Model` property (and even with a string that I removed from the code).

Comment: i think you have not added the ViewModel in your usercontrol resource...before using it in binding you need to add it as a usercontrol resource

Comment: @StepTNT Even if this is just an example, you should heed HighCore's advice. That's an important (fundamental... in fact one of the drivers) aspect of MVVM. I don't want to assume too much... but one with a good understanding of MVVM design goals probably wouldn't use a Grid object in a VM, even in an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are Setting the Source of the binding of UserControl.DataContext to the string ViewModel instead of an instance of ViewModel (that's why your error say "on 'ViewModel' 'System.String'")

.
To make it work you could for example use:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Or you could define you ViewModel in App.xaml or in your View resource `<vm:ViewModel x:Key="myViewModel"/>` and in you view use:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myViewModel}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be putting a UserControl (like Grid) in your view model; that's the beauty of the View. Based on your example, you probably want a control like the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx), which displays things in an Excel-like table. Consider the following:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Categories Category { get; set; }
    public Grid PresenterContent { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Model> _model;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_model != value)
            {
                _model = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Model);
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Model = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    }
}
```

This is what is in the code-behind (may not be *exactly* like this):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : public UserControl
{
    UserControl1( )
    {
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel( );
    }
}
```

And the Xaml would look like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Model}" />
```

The idea is that your ViewModel prepares the data for presentation, and the entire presentation is defined in the Xaml (View). Using the `"{Binding xxx}`" you may access properties on the object that is the `'DataContext'` of the current control. So the Xaml defines the children of the [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx), and every UserControl has a [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) to which objects on the UI (Xaml) can be bound. So you can bind your DataGrid's [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) (the source of the items that populate the grid) to the DataContext's Model property by saying `ItemsSource="{Binding Model}"`